# Android - Call notifyDataSetChanged() on recycler view ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I have a recycler view ListAdapter (coming from androidx)

I know that one is not supposed to use notifyDataSetChanged() any more with a ListAdaper but I am in a situation where it's necessary (onBindViewHolder() should be invoked without changing the submitlist)

The problem is that I have a compilation error when I call notifyDataSetChanged() like this:

```
binding.episodesRv.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Compilation error:

```
Smart cast to '({Adapter<(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder..
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder?)> & EpisodeListAdapter}..
EpisodeListAdapter)' is impossible, because 'bd.episodesRv.adapter' is a complex expression
```

The adapter :

```
class EpisodeListAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    var epiId: StateFlow<Long>,
    val selectEpisode: (episode: Episode) -> Unit,
    val delete: (episode: Episode) -> Unit,
) : ListAdapter<Episode, EpisodeViewHolder>(EPISODE_COMPARATOR) {
 ....
```

Comment: It can happen, if you trying to get something from the object, that could be null at this moment at any reason, and compiler can't perform the smart cast. In your case it might be an adapter. You can try non-null assertion for the call like binding.episodesRv.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged() if you are sure, that adapter is not null at the moment of the call.

Comment: Thanks Artem. bd.episodesRv.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged() works fine. Issue sovled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by Artem Chernousov in comments above. Thanks again.